# Java not able to see the derby database table when running

Tags: java, database, netbeans, database-connection, derby

## The Problem:

I am creating an application that requires the use of an integrated database but I am having issues getting my application to connect to the database/table. Unfortunately, my knowledge of Java connecting to databases is rather limited but everything I have read and watched seems to point to my code being correct.

## My Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:datahold;");
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from APP.DATASTORE");
        ResultSetMetaData meta=rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = meta.getColumnCount();
        for (int x = 1; x <= columnCount; x++)
            System.out.format("%20s",meta.getColumnName(x)+ " | ");

        while (rs.next()){
            System.out.println("");
            for (int x = 1; x <= columnCount; x++) System.out.format("%20s", rs.getString(x)+ " | ");
        }
        if (stat != null) stat.close();
        if (con != null) con.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}
```

## The Error:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'APP.DATASTORE' does not exist.BUILD 
SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

## My Data Base Setup:

[image: Data Base Setup]

I have tried removing the "APP." but this then results in the application not being able to find a table "ROOT.DATASTORE".

If anyone is able to help me out here that would be great!

## UPDATE:

I can now see that when running the application, it is creating the database files in the root of the package. Therefore, the embedded driver connection must be working (at least that's the way I see it). My question is should the database be located here or should it be held in the "dist" folder?

I am assuming it is not able to see the table because it is looking in the wrong location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question is rather simple as I found out after HOURS of tinkering.

Netbeans kindly creates a persistent xml file that stores some data that the application uses when it starts up. More precisely, when the database starts up. One of these options is which connection to use.

All I had to do was change this connection to my embedded driver connection and it is now working.

Comment: I am sorry but your answer is wrong. It was a problem of path of db installation. Notice that your netbeans was still connecting to previous table without creating it again. actually what you are doing is creating a new table. I understand what the problem was. the path of java db in your netbeans and the program that you are running are different.

Comment: And I think to make your program run you might again have appended db url with "create=true". which means create new database if it is not present. This way the db shown in netbeans and used by your program are completely different.

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer as I have since found the issue was the persistent file had the wrong connection set.

Answer (score 0):

You have put an semicolon there

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:datahold;");
```

remove it
here is correct code

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:datahold");
```

Comment: That's because it used to have ; create=true but I removed it to test. I have removed the semi colon and it still produces the same error.

Comment: Is your code is working in netbeans? @Petay87 I mean by using Netbeans GUI??

Comment: Yes - I am using the Netbeans IDE to create the application

Comment: @Petay87 Cannot help you this way. can you meet me in chatroom "http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59002/java-to-android"?

Comment: I have made a bit more progress with this. This is only an issue when using the embedded driver connection. I have also noticed that the database appears to be being created  but it is being put in the root of the package, should this not be in the "dist" folder?

Comment: The default Location of database used by your netbeans can be seen by [right click on `java DB` server > Properties > database location]. but location of your program's db depends.